# Set of all points that are of equal distance to any specific straight line and any specific point

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

So I know parabolas are like this, but only for line parallel to the $x$-or $y$-axis. Is it possible to do it for any line?

Taking it even further, what about the set of all points that are equal distance to a specific parabola and a specific point?

You can take this as far as you want, I'm just curious as to what is possible and how it would look like.

Comment: It is always a parabola whatever the line be (because of the definition itself). Take a line $y=ax+b$ and a point  $P(a,b)$, then plot what your definition say, i.e. 
$$\dfrac{|Ax-y+C|}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}=\sqrt{(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2}$$ and you will verify that  you do get a parabola.

Answer (score 1):

Well, a parabola is in fact defined as you said, the set of points that are equidistant from a given point and a given line, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabola#Definition_as_a_locus_of_points).

As for  your second question, you can use the definition you just gave. The locus of point that are equidistant from a given parabola and a given point, can be equally defined at the set of points that are equidistant from two given points and a line. I believe you can finish it from here.